# Anybody knows a way to connect a txt file to database which refreshing 30s per request

Tags: database, api, text, request

Here I have an issue for some txt file to be inserted into a database every 30s . so in the database, it's to store and keeps it. I want a proper solution for this please help anybody?

Answer (score 0):

To refresh a CSV or TXT file, you must ensure that it contains the same columns that are already matched with the data source. If the file that you reload is missing some columns, then you’ll get an error stating that your data reload has failed due to one or more missing columns.

Comment: Yeah I want a proper way to do that